# Solve the error in the simultaneous equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is: 
$$\begin{align}
\tag{1} 2x - 3y &= 3\\
\tag{2} 4x^2 - 9y^2 &= 3
\end{align}$$

From equation (1): 
$$\tag{3} 2x = 3 - 3y.$$
Substitute equation (3) in (2):
$$\begin{align}
4x^2 - 9y^2 &= 3\\
(2x)^2 - 9y^2 &= 3\\
(3 - 3y)^2 - 9y^2 &= 3\\
 [(3)^2 - 2\cdot 3\cdot 3y + (-3y)^2] - 9y^2 - 3 &= 0\\
 9 +18y + 9y^2 - 9y^2 - 3 &= 0\\
 -18y + 6 &= 0\\
-18y &= -6\\
y &= \frac 1 3
\end{align}$$

But the answer for y in my book is  $ - \frac 1 3\ $

Which one is right?

Comment: First line: $2x=3\color{red}+3y$.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "$2.3.3$" on the 4th line of the big block of equations?

Comment: @AviSteiner No doubt, he meant "$2\cdot3\cdot3$".

Comment: @DavidMitra Ah, OK. For Kiara: if you want to type a multiplication dot in latex, use `\cdot`.

Comment: Okay guys...thanks...it was a mistake :( @DavidMitra..um a she..not he :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your equation (3) is wrong. it will be 2x=3+3y and then try.
the solving process is alternatively done by using the formula a^2-b^2 in the LHS of (2) and then use eq (1).
This particular type of problem follow always this type method.

Answer (score 2):

There is other way:

$\ 2x - 3y = 3 \tag{1}$

$(2x - 3y)(2x + 3y) = 3 \tag{2} $

Using $(1)$ we have

$$ 2x - 3y = 3 $$
$$ 2x + 3y = 1 $$
 $$(1)+(2)$$
$$4x=4$$

Comment: To get equation numbers, say you want the line to be given the equation number (5), put `\tag{5}` at the beginning of the line (I think putting it at the end works too).

Comment: @Avi Steiner,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From $(3)$ you get $x$, so your solution is 
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
x&=&1  \\
y&=&\frac{1}{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Substitute these value in your equation then you see that all the equalities hold except the equality $(1)$. Here we get $1$ for the left-hand side and $3$ for the right-hand side. So apparently $(3)$ is erroneous.